# add condition additional div inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

hello guys is there any way to add additional div on ng-repeat.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class=" thumbnail-services col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" ng-repeat="service in services">
        <figure class="figure">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="{{service.name}}">
            <figcaption class="figure-caption">
                <h3>{{service.name}} <span> {{service.age}}</span></h3>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

i want to add `<div class="clearfix">` everythime its loop 2 times

like this

```
<div class="row">
      <div class=" thumbnail-services col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" ng-repeat="service in services">
           <figure class="figure">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="{{service.name}}">
                <figcaption class="figure-caption">
                     <h3>{{service.name}} <span> {{service.age}}</span></h3>
                </figcaption>
           </figure>
     </div>
     <div ng-if="$index % 2 == 0">
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

so to sum it up after loop 2 times just under closed div for cols it will add a new div class clearfix. is it possible?

Comment: ```<div ng-if="$index % 2 == 0">``` is this not working?

Comment: no, i think because i use ng-if after close tag of ng-repeat.but i need to add that class after each cols. any suggest sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ng-if` is outside the `ng-repeat`. Update based on your comment, add another div that will wrap the clearfix div and service div.

```
<div class="row">
      <div ng-repeat="service in services">
        <div class=" thumbnail-services col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <figure class="figure">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="{{service.name}}">
                  <figcaption class="figure-caption">
                      <h3>{{service.name}} <span> {{service.age}}</span></h3>
                  </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="$index % 2 == 0">
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yap i know but if i use it inside ngrepeat, the clearfix will be print on inside class thumbnail service. my goal is to be print outside thumbnail services.

Comment: oh i thought it must use ng-repeat on element that we want to loop. didnt know before. thank you sir